# C++ template refinement involving another typename?

Tags: c++, templates

Without using Boost, how can I write a function like:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(T t)
{
   ...
}

template<>
void myFunc(someclass<T> t)
{
    myFunc(t.get());
}
```

Update: I may have over analyzed this.  I was confused when I wanted the original

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(T t)
{
   ...
}
```

to work with vector.  I suppose I got confused because in specializations of template functions you omit the typename argument and I thought I needed the T still.

It appears one of the answers may already work.

Comment: [Describe the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). What exactly are you having trouble with? What do you want? Posting broken code and saying "make code like this" is like me saying "draw me a shape similar to a four sided circle".

Comment: Just how you did. Boost doesn't add templates, it just uses them (a lot). You need to know what classes you're expecting, the function purpose, and what specializations you need (what's `someclass<T>`, for example? a shared ptr?). If you know you'll be passing a `someclass` in, then the `T` should be in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you associate Boost with this. Anyway:

This won't work since `T` doesn't exist here.

```
template<>
void myFunc(someclass<T> t);
```

What you probably meant is:

```
template < typename T >
void myFunc(someclass<T> t);
```

Comment: You are right.  I over analyzed the original problem.  It was as simple as that!

Comment: Accept your own answer please.

Comment: Or your answer. I just wanted the question to be marked as answered :)